# R error type “Subscript out of bounds” with a loop (data.frame)

Tags: r

I am trying to concatenate two names of different companies in this format ( Company A & Company B) based on this table:

**Input**:

```
 companya <- c("AML Steels Ltd.") 
 companyb <- c("Dev Information Technology Ltd.")
 companyc <- c("Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd. ")
 companyd <- c("Navketan Merchants Ltd. ") 

 data_withconame1 <- data.frame(companya, companyb, companyc, companyd)
```

**And looking to have this (Output):**

```
   [1] "1,2" AML Steels Ltd. & Dev Information Techno.
   [1] "1,3"  AML Steels Ltd. & Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd.
   [1] "1,4"  AML Steels Ltd. & Navketan Merchants Ltd. 
   [1] "2,3" Dev Information Techno. & Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd.
   [1] "2,4" Dev Information Techno. & Navketan Merchants Ltd.
   [1] "3,4" Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd. & Navketan Merchants Ltd.
```

I have been trying with this loop, but I get

> Error in data_withconame1[j + 1, ] : subscript out of bounds

```
  i <- 1
  j <- 1

  for(i in 1:length(data_withconame1)-1){

   j <- i+1
   while(j <= length(data_withconame1)-1){
   str(data_withconame1)

    print(paste(data_withconame1[i+1,],data_withconame1[j+1,]),sep=","))

    j <- j+1
    }}
```

Comment: When you say you are "looking to have something like this (Output)" that's not good enough. You need to say **as precisely as possible** what you want. Do you really want strings printed or returned? Do you really want the indexes in quote marks separated by commas ("1,2") as well? Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(companya, companyb, companyc, companyd, stringsAsFactors = F)


library(magrittr)
lapply(seq_along(df) %>% .[-length(.)], function(x){
        y <- (x + 1):ncol(df)
        paste0(x, ',', y, ' ', df[x], ' & ',df[y])
        }) %>% 
    unlist


# [1] "1,2 AML Steels Ltd. & Dev Information Technology Ltd."              
# [2] "1,3 AML Steels Ltd. & Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd. "                
# [3] "1,4 AML Steels Ltd. & Navketan Merchants Ltd. "                     
# [4] "2,3 Dev Information Technology Ltd. & Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd. "
# [5] "2,4 Dev Information Technology Ltd. & Navketan Merchants Ltd. "     
# [6] "3,4 Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd.  & Navketan Merchants Ltd. "
```

Or, without `magrittr` and `%>%`

```
unlist(
  lapply(seq_along(df)[-length(seq_along(df))], function(x){
        y <- (x + 1):ncol(df)
        paste0(x, ',', y, ' ', df[x], ' & ',df[y])
        })
)
```

Comment: Thank you... it returns me this: Error in lapply(seq_along(df) %>% .[-length(.)], function(x) { : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: You need the `magrittr` library. Or you could use my edit without `%>%`. I was just saving myself some typing.

Comment: Would I be able to get it in the same format of the first table? @Renu

Comment: What I meant, is if I can get the output within a data.frame of one column as well (like the input).. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes. Wrap the whole thing in `data.frame`. So `newdf <- data.frame(some.colname = <CODE HERE>)`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the company names in a vector (not a data frame):

```
companies=c("A corp","B factory","C inc", "D plc")
```

you can use `combn` to get the combinations and `apply` to work on each combination with a function:

```
combos = apply(combn(1:length(companies),2),2,
   function(ij){
    paste(companies[ij],collapse=" & ")
    })

combos
# [1] "A corp & B factory" "A corp & C inc"     "A corp & D plc"    
# [4] "B factory & C inc"  "B factory & D plc"  "C inc & D plc"
```

That is a vector of the combination names that you can then do more stuff with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is I do get the table from a data.frame shape... @Spacedman

Comment: @Robin_Hcp This solution works with `companies` defined as `companies <- lapply(df, as.character)`.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that `data.frame()` converts your company names into factors. Setting `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` fixes that.
Other than that, `combn()` to pair up the names, `apply()` and `paste(., collapse)` to collate. Similar approach to collate the indexes, and then make into a table using `cbind()`.

```
companya <- c("AML Steels Ltd.")  
companyb <- c("Dev Information Technology Ltd.")  
companyc <- c("Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd. ")
companyd <- c("Navketan Merchants Ltd. ") 

data_withconame1 <- data.frame(companya, companyb, 
                               companyc, companyd,
                               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

cbind(
  apply(combn(seq_along(data_withconame1[1,]), 2), 2, paste, collapse=","),
  apply(combn(data_withconame1[1,], 2), 2, paste, collapse=" & ")
)

#      [,1]  [,2]                                                             
# [1,] "1,2" "AML Steels Ltd. & Dev Information Technology Ltd."              
# [2,] "1,3" "AML Steels Ltd. & Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd. "                
# [3,] "1,4" "AML Steels Ltd. & Navketan Merchants Ltd. "                     
# [4,] "2,3" "Dev Information Technology Ltd. & Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd. "
# [5,] "2,4" "Dev Information Technology Ltd. & Navketan Merchants Ltd. "     
# [6,] "3,4" "Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd.  & Navketan Merchants Ltd. "
```

Answer (score 0):

For a very concise base R solution you can use `interaction` and cast the `levels` into a `matrix` whose elements are then the combinations you are after.

```
mat <- matrix(
    levels(interaction(unlist(data_withconame1), unlist(data_withconame1), sep = " & ")), 
    ncol = 4);
diag(mat) <- 0;
#[,1]
#[1,] "0"
#[2,] "Dev Information Technology Ltd. & AML Steels Ltd."
#[3,] "Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd.  & AML Steels Ltd."
#[4,] "Navketan Merchants Ltd.  & AML Steels Ltd."
# [,2]
#[1,] "AML Steels Ltd. & Dev Information Technology Ltd."
#[2,] "0"
#[3,] "Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd.  & Dev Information Technology Ltd."
#[4,] "Navketan Merchants Ltd.  & Dev Information Technology Ltd."
# [,3]
#[1,] "AML Steels Ltd. & Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd. "
#[2,] "Dev Information Technology Ltd. & Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd. "
#[3,] "0"
#[4,] "Navketan Merchants Ltd.  & Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd. "
# [,4]
#[1,] "AML Steels Ltd. & Navketan Merchants Ltd. "
#[2,] "Dev Information Technology Ltd. & Navketan Merchants Ltd. "
#[3,] "Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd.  & Navketan Merchants Ltd. "
#[4,] "0"
```

For example,

```
mat[1, 2]
#[1] "AML Steels Ltd. & Dev Information Technology Ltd."
mat[1, 3]
#[1] "AML Steels Ltd. & Jyotirgamya Enterprises Ltd. "
```

and so on.